# Effect size calculation

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, ecology

I am conducting a meta-analysis on the diet of predators. This diet is expressed as the proportion of aquatic vs terrestrial prey. I have a value (% of aquatic prey) for each species for each site of each study. I can't find any satisfying way to calculate an effect size.

Any advice ?

Thanks

Denis

Comment: What would be wrong with using the proportions you have, possibly transformed?

Answer (score 0):

Several options exist. For example, Cohen h or Odds Ratio. Cohen h is usually associated with sample size determination and power analysis, but the Odds Ratio can be used for meta-analysis (see last two links).

https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Proportions_using_Effect_Size.pdf

https://www.campbellcollaboration.org/escalc/html/EffectSizeCalculator-OR2.php

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28169977

Comment: I think the OP has a single proportion from each study so could not compute an OR.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The proportion as noted by mdewey seems logical, or present as an odds of the event, p/(1-p), or Cohen (1988, Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences, p. 147) discusses effect size g as the departure of the probability from .50 (i.e., g = p-.5), but that is probably most suitable for power and sample size determination.

Comment: Hi. Yes, this is not the result of a test and I have no control. So I can't calculate the usual Odds ratio. The g value ou odds of the event sounds promising. I will follow these leads. Thanks